# javascript how to make the dropdown value to reset to intiall value(checking the check box)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

"INSERT MODE"

i have  check box in one  "tr". and  another   dropdown control  in another  "tr"
intially dropdown control will be  invisiable intially .

but once the user   checks the  check box. the  dropdown control should be  visiable and  he can select the value.  but again  the user  unchecks  the check box  the dropdown  should be  set  to  default value   that is "--selec--"

"UPDATE  MODE" intailly 
checkbox.Test =  dt.cloumn["state"].tostring();

```
if(checkbox.Test!= "")
{
checkbox.checked=true;
//then  value  dropdown  value  should  be  shown like"india"
}
else
{
checkbox.checked="false"
//then  value  dropdown  value  should   be  default "--select"
}
```

in insert  mode  checkbox  willbe   unchecked
  in update  mode  if  checkbox  in checked then the value  of  dropdown  should be  shown"india"
  in update  mode  if  checkbox  in unchecked then the value  of  dropdown  should be  shown default"-select-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#theSelect").toggle(0);
        $("#activate").click(activate)
    })

    function activate(e) {
        $("#theSelect").toggle((e.target.checked));

        if (!e.target.checked) {  // reset selection
            $("#theSelect option[value='--Select--']").attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
    }
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="theSelect">
                <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                <option value="foo">foo</option>
                <option value="bar">bar</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="activate" /> Activate
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks  for the  replay  
as here you  know that  "-Select-"  will  come  at  "0"  postion   but in my case    select will  be the  last  postion in dropdown 
<td>     
       <select id="theSelect">                               <option value="foo">foo</option>                <option value="bar">bar</option> 
<option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>            </select>        </td>
  because  today   my dropdown  values may contain  5  items  . in future  it may contain  10  items  under it.
  so  how  will i  place  my  select value  firist in bropdown on clicking checking  box

Comment: made   few  changes  worked   fine  to  suit my  needs.
  thanks   Lance Rushing